Dropdown Menu isn't Showing when Overflowing Certain Selector of Specific URLs, Scrollbar is To Thick and doesn't have a delay when I Hovering It
I use "Stylus" addon/extension in Firefox and Chrome and I know that webkit-scrollbar is not supported in Firefox, so I used scrollbar-width. I know that some URLs have some limitation to display a word or a sentence without being clipped (for example lists of ChatGPT title at the leftmost panel at chatgpt.com, or other websites), so I use overflow:auto !important and text-overflow:clip !important to make the entire sentence visible. I wrote a style that tends to match "everything" named MyStyle. Someone in StackOverflow suggested that I have to do this:
.container{
  overflow:auto !important;
  text-overflow:clip !important;
  display: inline-block !important; /*Add This*/
}

.container.dropdown{
  display: block !important; /*Add This*/
}

The problem is, some websites have containers that clip a title inside it and some of those containers contain a dropdown menu. The .dropdown selector maybe have different name in different URLs, they can be ..dropdown-menu, .navigation-menu, or anything.
My wish is to make the button, li, ul li, ol li, span, a, div button, div ol li, div ul li, div li, div span, div a, div select, select, div input, input, div label, label, div option, option, button div, li div, ol li div, ul li div, span div, a div, select div, input div, label div, option div to be:

If those selectors contain dropdown menu, it must be visible although I overflowing it (overflow:auto) (First priority)
have a scrollbar when I hover to it and the weight of the scrollbar can be adjusted (both when I hover and not). Yes, I also previously added scrollbar-width: thin !Important; and when I hovered it, it seems didn't change the weight. I want this can be applied in both Chrome and Firefox.
I want to have the delay of 2s to show the scrollbar after I hover on it

Previously I did this in MyStyle to solve my 3 problems (it is the implementation of .container):
button, li, ul li, ol li, span, a, div button, div ol li, div ul li, div li, div span, div a,
div select, select, div input, input, div label, label, div option, option, button div, li div,
ol li div, ul li div, span div, a div, select div, input div, label div, option div{
  overflow-x: auto !important;
  text-overflow: clip !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-out !important;
  /*scrollbar-width: thin !important;*/
  /*display: inline-block !important;*/
}

Because we have different tag name (the dropdown menu can be <li>, <p>, <i>, etc) and different ID/class to specify dropdown selector, I add this (it is the implementation of .container.dropdown) to MyStyle:
button > *, li > *, ul li > *, ol li > *, span > *, a > *, div button > *, div ol li > *, div ul li > *, div li > *, div span > *, div a > *,
div select > *, select > *, div input > *, input > *, div label > *, label > *, div option > *, option > *, button div > *, li div > *,
ol li div > *, ul li div > *, span div > *, a div > *, select div > *, input div > *, label div > *, option div > *{
  display: block !important;
  z-index: 1000 !important;
}

But nothing can give me the solution.
Does anyone can help?
